# cvLoadImage is undefined but other functions are working just fine

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I just installed opencv4.1.1-cv14_cv15, followed a guide that helped me to setup the project and only the "cvLoadImage" function isn't found.

I did the following to include and add opencv to the project:
1. Install
2. set Path to opencv in environment variables
3. c\c++ -> general -> additional include directories and added the path C:\opencv\build\include  under all configurations
4. added the libs and bins of cv14 and cv15 in linker->general->additional library directories
5. under the "debug" configuration I added to linker->input the libs: opencv_world411d.lib and opencv_ts411d.lib
6. under the "release" configuration I added to linker->input the libs:
opencv_world411.lib and opencv_ts411.lib

Tried x86 and x64 and nothing worked...

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui_c.h>
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"

int main()
{
int i;
cvNamedWindow("Display Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

IplImage* image = cvLoadImage("PATH", 1);
if (image)
{
    cvShowImage("Display window", image);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    system("pause");
    cvReleaseImage(&image);
}
}
```

Thank you and have a nice day!
 - Anthon

Comment: Just a remark that does not answer the question: `IplImage`, `cvLoadImage` and so on are part of a (very) old opencv interface and are kept only for backward compatibility. You should use `cv::Mat image=cv::imread("PATH",1);`

Comment: **don't use obsolete C api!**, which was removed since OpenCV 4. And follow up-to-date tutorials, like: https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/deb/tutorial_display_image.html

Comment: Thank you @xiawi and Miki, I found out about it about at the same time you commented. I already change my approach and I looked at some up-to-date guides.